# Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to create a half circle radial menu?

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, radial

The following is a crude picture on what I want to achieve.

[image: Half Circle]

That's the end result. The black square in the picture will be a toggle button. When that button is pressed, a half circle will appear. Ideally, it would animate from the right side and come down to the bottom. The items for the menu would appear inside of the red lines.

I need direction on where to begin on creating this control. It's clear I need to create a WPF UserControl, but I don't know what else is required in order to get it going.

Any direction would be helpful.

Comment: Look up "pie menu" for WPF. Have some results. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/522343/A-Pie-Menu-for-WPF http://alexpkent.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/wpf-radial-context-menu-pie-menu/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955250/piemenu-for-wpf

Comment: please dont ask the same question again just because the other one didnt get an answer after a hour.

Comment: @TimKatheteStadler That's not why I posted again. I posted again because people chose to be unhelpful in that post and closed the question for no good reason. The question was closed, so no answer would be given because the only people who would be able to see it would those who already commented. Which are only those who did not want to be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create this kind of control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320930/how-to-create-this-kind-of-control)

Comment: A good rule I learned ages ago about custom WPF controls is it's easy to make things look the way you want, but hard to change behavior. So find a control that behaves the way you want, then make it look like you want. In this case a split-button or popup-button might work better. In any case get it behaving correctly first, then make it look right.